# socket.io error; cant establish a a connection at wss server

Tags: websocket, socket.io

I am getting an error and am trying to get an explanation as to its meaning. Anyone who can shed light on the meaning and the fix would be appreciated.

```
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://myurl.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=66o3W59fgV4wklBbAAAO.
```